# Custom JQuery Validation not be be applied if a particular option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

**Here is my**  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1z7mevct/2/).

In the Fiddle, it will have the ruel - required for both first and second element.

(It works good in localhost but not responding in jsfiddle).

What i need is if first is chosen "don't ask" then the second field should not be required (rule should not apply to the second one).

**How can i do this ?**

**Here is the Script for Validation :**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#data").validate({
        rules: {
            first:{ 
              required: true,
            },
            second:{ 
              required: true,
              number: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            first: "Please choose any Company",            
            second: "Please enter valid number for the Total Number of Seats"
        }
    })

    $('#driver').click(function() {
        $("#data").valid();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function for the require rule, in your case:

```
$("#data").validate({
    rules: {
        first:{ 
          required: true,
        },
        second:{ 
          required: function () {
               // current value of the select field no:
               // this field is not required
               if ($("#first").val() == 'no') {
                   return false;
               } else {
                   return true;
               }
           },
          number: true
        },
    },
    messages: {
        first: "Please choose any Company",            
        second: "Please enter valid number for the Total Number of Seats"
    }
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1z7mevct/4/) is here.

Comment: Thanks, Works like Great !!\